# Converting tabular data with multiline string field using FME?

Tags: convert, fme-form, well-known-text

I have data in a table. One of the fields has pairs of coordinates. The coordinate pairs represent a point and the points joined in order to represent a line. The number of coordinate pairs varies. There are many tables!

How do I convert this table to a spatial dataset (i.e. shapefile) using FME?

Here is the content from one of the cells in the table (the 'shape' field). This is an example of 2 coordinate pairs but some have 10 pairs so I can't easily use 'text to columns' in Excel.

```sql
MULTILINESTRING ((138.5418028 -35.0290507909, 138.54179 -35.028988))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string with coordinates is [WKT (Well-known text)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry).

In FME you could use a GeometryReplacer to (re)create the geometry of the feature based on the WKT string.

[image: example]

Comment: This was what I needed. I didn't realise that it was a WKT format.
Here is another ESRI link that would also do the conversion using Python: 
https://community.esri.com/thread/216142-exporting-wkt-string-from-csv-to-shapefile